# what existing polkadot network monitoring tools are out there?

Tags: network, monitoring

It would be nice to build a list of tools that are useful to monitor the network.

Comment: As far as I know Substrate comes with a Prometheus exporter built-in, with that you could have metrics to monitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the resources that I am aware of:

- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-tools-index#network-monitoring--reporting
- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-monitor-your-node
- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/node-metrics